# no performance difference between different number of map tasks (1, 2, 4..)

Tags: python, hadoop

I am very new to hadoop and am testing the performance difference between different number of map tasks and reduce tasks. The `file size is about 5GB` and hadoop is installed on `4 core/8 core machine (hyper threading)`.

The map and reduce were written in python, so I specify the number of map tasks by `-D mapred.map.tasks=2` and specify the number of reduce tasks by `-D mapred.reduce.tasks=2`.

## Problem

The problem is that the result doesn't show any performance difference between different number of map tasks..

Result

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|   map    |  reduce  |  time    |
+----------+----------+----------+
|    1     |    1     | 47m 09s  |
|    2     |    1     | 45m 35s  |
|    4     |    1     | 46m 30s  |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|    1     |    2     | 38m 37s  |
|    2     |    2     | 39m 22s  |
|    4     |    2     | 39m 29s  |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|    1     |    4     | 38m 18s  |
|    2     |    4     | 38m 48s  |
|    4     |    4     | 38m 23s  |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

It seems that there is a few minute difference between using 1 reduce task and using 2 reduce tasks, but no difference when I change the number of map tasks.Is it that all the tasks are performed on only one node, and the map tasks are not running in parallel?

What could be causing this? I would appreciate any information.

## Edit

I also tried specifying these values in `mapred-site.xml` instead of in the command but didn't make any changes.

Comment: You can't force the number of map tasks for a job. It is entirely depending on the split sizes and that is fixed, because your file is always 5gb large. What you are seeing is your file slowly beeing cached in OS memory.

Comment: Is the input file a single 5GB file (compressed?) What's your block size for this file(s)?

Comment: @ChrisWhite the file is not compressed and it's a single 5GB file. What's a block size? Is it the split size? If so, I didn't specify so it should be the default 64MB.

Answer (score 0):

Option `mapred.map.tasks` is not a directive [but a hint](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces) to hadoop, so how did you check actual number of map tasks executed? While job is performed, you can monitor running jobs in job tracker and running tasks in [task tracker](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/quickstart.html). Also, you can `ssh` on your hadoop machine, and check for running map/reduce tasks, those will be java processes.

You can try set `mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` in your `mapred-site.xml` to bound mappers per node to see parallel execution benefits.

For more performance monitor options, you probably might opt to install [Ganglia](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GangliaMetrics), also see this blog entry: [Monitoring Hadoop beyond Ganglia](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2013/04/18/so-what-monitoring-hadoop-beyond-ganglia/)

Comment: I've tried `mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` but I still get the same result when I specified 1 map task and 2 map tasks...

Comment: @kabichan did you check amount of map tasks run per node in tracker? and btw, what your map task is doing? If it's low on cpu usage, then you are actually testing speed of IO on you machine.

Comment: @kabichan what hadoop version you're using?

Comment: the hadoop version is 1.2.1

Comment: @kabichan remember that localhost refers to your namenode